# For a hash table, how does one conclude that n=O(m), where n is the number of elements in the table and m is the number of slots?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, complexity-theory, clrs

On page 260 of CLRS, it says,

> If the number of hash-table slots is at least proportional to the number of elements in the table, we have n = O(m) and, consequently, a = n/m = O(m)/m = O(1). Thus, searching takes constant time on average.

How does one conclude that n = O(m)? How can n (total number of elements in table) be capped by m (the number of slots)? Shouldn't it be m = O(n)?

Comment: You might start by revisiting what O(m) means.

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I somehow read n = O(m) as "worst case of n". Thanks @ScottHunter!

Answer (score 0):

O(m) refers to the worst case limit of the number of slots, which is n, the number of items in the hash table. An example of this is the direct-address table.